# Getting Japanese fonts (hiragana & katakana) and entering text into LibreOffice (NB Not changing entire system language to Japanese)

Tags: software-installation

I want to use some Japanese text entry in a word processor (eg LibreOffice). I have a Japanese capable keyboard. I haven’t found any exchanges which tell me how to do this. I’m a novice with RPi.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. I wonder if this question is really specific to the Pi or if it will get better responses somewhere else... somewhere where people know more about LibreOffice? Edit to add: well, if you're good with the existing answer, that'll be that.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts installed into the system will be available to individual applications (i.e., you don't need to install the fonts into Libre Office).

The fonts are available in specific packages.  To search for them:

```
apt search font | grep -B1 -A2 -i japan
```

This is quite a list; for easier navigation you might want to tack `| less` onto the end; `less` won't make the list shorter, but it makes scrolling a bit easier and allows you to search for specific things using <kbd>/</kbd> (search forward) and <kbd>?</kbd> (search backward).  I did not find "hira" or "kata" that way, but presumably there is something that will meet your needs.  The switches used with `grep` are explained in `man grep`.

The package name is before a slash on the first line of each listing, e.g.:

```
xfonts-kaname/stable 1.1-10 all
   Kaname Cho 12 dot Japanese Kanji, Latin 1 fonts for X11
```

To install that, use `sudo apt install xfonts-kaname`.

You may have to restart Libre Office afterward.  Note that not all fonts are acceptable to all applications (e.g., some of them are console fonts, which are distinct from those used in a GUI), so if you don't can't find whatever, try something else.

I believe what you want to prefer are "TrueType" fonts, this is mentioned in their description.